# AWS Cognito SDK for Android did not respect the Timeout

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

Currently I am working on an Android app using Cognito SDK for Android and everything works perfectly.

A week ago customer wanted me to test the app by simulating bad Network and here I found the problem, the below code is what I am setting now in my app:

```
private static final int COGNITO_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5000;

private static final int COGNITO_SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 10000;

...

if (userPool == null) {
    // Create a user pool with default ClientConfiguration
    final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = (new ClientConfiguration())
            .withMaxErrorRetry(0)
            .withConnectionTimeout(COGNITO_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT) // 5000ms
            .withSocketTimeout(COGNITO_SOCKET_TIMEOUT) // 10000ms
            .withMaxConnections(100);
    userPool = new CognitoUserPool(context, ApiHelper.getPoolId(), ApiHelper.getClientId(),
            ApiHelper.getClientSecret(), clientConfiguration,
            Regions.fromName(ApiHelper.getRegion()));
}
```

Here you can see I set my connection timeout to 5000ms and socket time out to 10000s, but not like that when I try to simulate bad network, I expect it will throw exception in 15000ms instead it is more than a minutes, here is the network I simulate by Android studio simulator:
[image]

And here the log throw by Cognito:

```
2019-12-24 18:37:43.135 11081-11081/com.xxxxx.blockchain.android.xxxxxx E/ListMatchesFragment: onFailure: Failed to authenticate user -> Failed to authenticate user
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.exceptions.CognitoInternalErrorException: Failed to authenticate user
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser.getCachedSession(CognitoUser.java:986)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser$5.run(CognitoUser.java:698)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
 Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: failed to connect to cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2a05:d018:478:8a01:bb35:4249:57d0:f234 (port 443) from /fe80::30c7:d6ff:fe5f:3a16 (port 46202) after 5000ms
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:441)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:6319)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.initiateAuth(AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:4283)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser.refreshSession(CognitoUser.java:2378)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser.getCachedSession(CognitoUser.java:976)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser$5.run(CognitoUser.java:698) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2a05:d018:478:8a01:bb35:4249:57d0:f234 (port 443) from /fe80::30c7:d6ff:fe5f:3a16 (port 46202) after 5000ms
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:191)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
```

The log also said that the cognito fail with time out 5000s, but in fact it is a minutes. :(

Any help to set the time out right?

Many thanks and regards,

Viet